# Implementing JSON Schema in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsonschema

How I can implement JSON Schema v0.7 or 2020-12 in Jmeter 5.4.3? I need to validate incoming REST responses.

I tried Schema Assertion plugin, but it didn't work as expected. It works only with v0.4 and seems to mix variables from different Treads.

Comment: Pls add a reproduciable example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [json-sKema](https://github.com/erosb/json-sKema) library, it seems to [support support 2020-12 draft](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html)

1. Download [json-sKema-0.8.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.erosb/json-sKema/0.8.0) from Maven Central and drop it to ["lib" folder of your JMeter installation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
3. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which response you need to validate against a JSON schema
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import com.github.erosb.jsonsKema.JsonParser
   import com.github.erosb.jsonsKema.SchemaLoader
   import com.github.erosb.jsonsKema.Validator

   def schemaStringValue = 'you-json-schema-here'

   def jsonValue = new JsonParser(schemaStringValue).parse()

   def schema = new SchemaLoader(jsonValue).load()

   def validator = Validator.forSchema(schema)

   def failure = validator.validate(new JsonParser(prev.getResponseDataAsString()).parse())

   if (failure != null) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failure.causes.each { cause -> cause }.collect { cause -> cause.message }.join(System.getProperty('line.separator')))
   }
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: So I need to create json schema in .json format and in schemaStringValue = filePath ? Am I right? And how can I insert json schema in JSR223 Assertion Script?

Comment: can you help me with above comment?

Comment: Your above comment says "So I need to create json schema in .json format and in schemaStringValue = filePath ? Am I right? And how can I insert json schema in JSR223 Assertion Script?" and this is exactly what you need to do. I hope you can copy and paste a piece of JSON into JMeter's JSR223 Assertion